# Android - Page heading Left-center alignment with Background

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a problem with the page heading to be left-center of background irrespective of text size.

The text should be center of background irrespective of the text size.

I have used the following layout.xml for the textview:

```
    <TableLayout
           android:id="@+id/widget3d8"
           android:layout_width="306dip"
           android:layout_height="26dip"
           android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
           android:paddingRight="8px"
           android:layout_x="5px"
           android:layout_y="10px"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
           android:background="#104082">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/committeename"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_x="0px"
                      android:layout_y="100px"
                      android:paddingLeft="10px"
                      android:text=" "
                      android:textSize="12sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
              </TableLayout>
```

Please help me how to make the text to be left-centered of the backgound irrespective of the text size. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the TextView have the same height as it's parent and set the gravity to vertically center the content.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/committeename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="100px"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:text=" "
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

Also set the textview to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```